# Which days recommended for a women to do headbath?

Tags: scripture, women, tradition

Which days of a week are recommended for women to do head bath?

Are there any forbidden days to do head bath for a women?

Comment: Tuesday and Friday. For men, Wednesday and Saturday. Reason is planteary rays of those days will be effective if we take headbath. Tue = Mars. Fri = Venus.
WED = Mercury. SAT = Saturn

Comment: @AkshayS Men are supposed to do it daily. But as it is not possible, they chant a mantra and do only on specific days.

Comment: @AkshayS, Sarvabhouma is right, that every day men have to wash their head, otherwise it is not counted as bath. i remember as a young lad i would only wet my head on Saturday. But that is for oil(sesame/gingelly)-bath. People mistakenly think that head need not be washed daily. Every day - head wash. Saturday - oil + head wash. But for women, the rule is relaxed, in fact they should not wash head everyday. Only on Tue, Fri, and Ekadashi. Sprinkling turmeric water and brushing hair on other days is equivalent to head-bath for women.

Comment: @ram I think I mixed up oil head bath. But for women Tuesday and Fridays are days. Because I remember growing up by parents saying men should not take oil bath on Tue and Fri and also not cut nails.... because those days are for women.

Comment: By head bath do u mean Abhayanga snana?

Comment: @Rickross I'm asking for a head bath. So abhyanga snana is also included...

Comment: I don't know whether for a simple head bath rules are given or not .. abhyanga snana is a special kind of bath and which has restricted/allowed days @hanugm

Comment: @Rickross is it a special kind of head bath?

Comment: All kinds of baths are head baths only as per my knowledge .. abhyanga bath is oil massage+bath @hanugm

Comment: I guess everyone has to bath daily whether women or men and bath isn't complete if the head is not wet .. This is wht I know @hanugm

Comment: @Rickross oh! Okay

Comment: But I may be wrong .. women may hv separate rules for bathing but Im not aware of those @hanugm